# Hover change opacity

Tags: css, wordpress, hover, widget, siteorigin

I'm curently creating my own website and using siteorigin page builder on wordpress. The problem is they don't have an option for hover, so I created a custom css to make a hover effect on a background color.
When I hover on a specific "div" or "child" of the background, it changes the opacity of this one differently than the rest. Here a picture to demonstrate the problem.

[hover problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zACvv.png)

As you can see, the blue are differents, with the same rule applied to the class of the background named ".featr".

Any help? Thanks

Comment: We can't help you fix your code without seeing it. Please edit your question to include your CSS/HTML.

Comment: It is impossible to help you with what you need unless we can see the code.

Comment: It is fixed, the problem was the little space bar between the class and hover. But now my transition isn't working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

hover selector must follow the class so in this case it should be:

```
.featr:hover
```

and not:

```
.featr :hover
```

Yeah, but post all your code if you need help. I don't think you need the transition

**in response to comment below**
So you need to state the start of background-color (.featr) and then the ending state (.featr:hover).
transition takes the background css and eases Linearly for half a second. You should include all transition lines below because it works for differently for each browser.

```
.featr {
background:rgba(0,0,0,1);
-o-transition: background 0.5s linear;
-moz-transition: background 0.5s linear;
-khtml-transition: background 0.5s linear;
-webkit-transition: background 0.5s linear;
-ms-transition: background 0.5s linear;
transition: background 0.5s linear;
}

.featr:hover {
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Comment: I've never had such a facepalm in my whole life... I feel so dumb now, literally a little spacebar messed up the whole thing.
Is it possible that someone explain me why is that? the importance of that spacebar?
Also, if I want to add a transition, how do I do it? Because when I removed the spacebar, it removed the transition effect aswell, it's no longer working.

Comment: Hey we all have those kind of days. But help us by giving us all the information you can, don't make use guess what you are doing. Oh the space separated the class from the selector so css didn't know you meant that you want the class featr when the mouse hovered over